# Angular app can't call Flask server API after deploying in Google cloud

Tags: angular, flask, google-cloud-platform

I have some issues when I tried to practice using Google cloud. I'm trying to deploy Flask as a back-end server to Google cloud, and Angular as a front-end app.

However, there is a message `500 Server Error`, and CORS blocking for Angular app request to Flask server. This happens after I deployed both in the separate Google cloud projects.

I'm not sure that I should deploy the server in production mode or not, but I didn't do that. Could it be possible that you will give me suggestion?

Comment: Provide more information on how the error occurred. Maybe some header data or a screenshot of the request and response would help

Answer (score 1):

You should enable [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on your `flask` backend hosted on GCP.

> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows
>   restricted resources on a web page to be requested from another domain
>   outside the domain from which the first resource was served

Check theses resources :

- https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- [Flask/Flask-CORS: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57762709/flask-flask-cors-cors-header-access-control-allow-origin-missing)
- [How to enable CORS in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594893/how-to-enable-cors-in-flask)

For example:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": ["http://localhost:4200", "URL_ON_GCP"]}})
```

where `URL_ON_GCP` is the URL of your hosted backend, for example:

- https://YOUR_SERVICE-dot-YOUR_APP.appspot.com (on GAE)